# Populate int array with for loop in Java

Tags: java

I have an array named numbers that I want to populate with a for loop:

```
    int[] numbers;

    for ( int i = 0; i <=10; i++)
    {
        // want to populate the array with a sequence of 0-10
    }
```

How can I populate the 11 values generated from the above for loop into my array?

Comment: Who knows that you might just do it you attempt _something_.

Comment: Have you ever checked a Java tutorial? Search for Java array access!

Comment: You really should work your way through a Java tutorial or text book. You're not going to get very far if you try to learn Java like this, nor does this make a particularly appropriate [so] question.

Comment: How would you like to populate your array? Do you want some random order like `5,10,4,7,...` from smallest to highest `0,1,2,3,...` or maybe some other way? What element should be placed at position indexed `[i]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to define what `numbers` is, you have only declared it.

```
int[] numbers = new int[11];
```

Then insert the values you want.

```
for ( int i = 0; i <=10; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **Java 7 or lower**, do this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[11];

for ( int i = 0; i <=10; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = i;
}
```

For **Java 8**, there is a more concise way to do this:

```
int[] numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10).toArray()
```

Comment: First line should end `new int[11];`

Comment: The Java 8 solution is nice! They seem to have copied that from python :)

Comment: Java 8 has made many things easier, particularly with collections.